# What is Blogger API reading quota?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, blogger

I am going to create a simple blog app which has included only reading facility (list/search/get). So, what is the quota limitation for reading in **Blogger API**? In my **Quotas** section which show as follows,

*Queries per day    10,000

Queries per 100 seconds per user    100*

I wanted know that what is the reading data quota limit from above stats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10,000 request (list/search/get) per day; with the limit of 100 request per 100 second for each unique IP address.

These numbers are since, as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#api-specific_quota):

> Depending on the API, Quota information may include requests per day,
>   requests per minute, and requests per minute per user.

Additionally, according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage) you may modify these limits given your preference and performance, as well as monitor your API Usage following [this](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/monitoring).